# Pandas to convert a date object list into a string

Tags: python, pandas

Not able to convert date object to string using pandas package. I have tried `date[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` but I'm sure this is not part of pandas.

```
def maxi(self):
    date = self.query('select max(date)  from records')
    print date
```

date prints -

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 6, 6),)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `tuple` inside the list, you can call `next(iter())` to access the tuple and then call the `0` th index to access the `datetime` value .You need:

```
#date=[(datetime.date(2019, 6, 6),)]
next(iter(date))[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#'2019-06-06'
```